# margin top negative value issue css

Tags: css

I have a div inside another div. I need to pull up the inside div out of the container div. I used the following code. If i use margin top in negative value the container div also move up with the inside div. I couldn't use `position absolute` for some alignment issue.

Code:

```
    <div style="background-color:#999999; width:150px; height:300px;">
        <div style="position:relative; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#006633; margin-top:-50px;"></div>
</div>
```

How to achieve this with just position relative?

Comment: `float` the inside div to left or right.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `margin-top` use `top`

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/VPBgX/)

```
top: -10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `relative` position, you should use `top` instead of `margin-top`.

Here is some [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jLjwv/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected css with [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4J8Vy/5/)

```
<div style="background-color:#999999; width:150px; height:300px;">
        <div style="position:relative; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#006633; position:relative;top:-50px;left:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to just apply a little change in your Css structure and have a brief idea about positioning in css. This [**LINK**](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) will help you gain some more knowledge about positioning.

HTML elements are placed `position:static` by default. So if you want your inner `div` to overlap parent `div`, you must use css property `top` which is ideal in case of `position:relative` elements.

here is a [**DEMO.**](http://jsbin.com/IHaPuXO/1/edit)